# How can I change the value of a selection field on create function?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I wanna change the value of `status` once I click save. `status` is a selection field `[('ok', 'Ok'),('tobe', 'Not Ok')]`

```py
    status = fields.Selection(
        readonly=False,
        default='tobe',
        related= 'name.status'      
    )
```

```py
    @api.model
    def create(self, values):
        self.status= 'ok'
        line = super(MyClass, self).create(values)
        return line
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Status is a related field so after creating change the status of you many2one field.

```py
  @api.model
  def create(self, values):
         rec = super(YouClassName, self).create(values)
         # here change the status. 
         rec.name.status = 'ok'
         return rec
```

Answer (score 3):

The error is in your selection field declaration. It should be like this:

```py
status = fields.Selection([('ok', "OK"),('not ok', "Not OK"),],default='tobe')

@api.multi
def write(self, vals):
    vals['status'] = 'ok'
    ret = super(Your-Class-Name-here, self).write(vals)
```

By default, readonly on every field is false, so no need specifying it inside the selection field.

Please, notify me if this solve your challenge.
Thanks

Comment: @SOS-Mona This is the correct answer. Selection fields require a `selection` parameter that defines what the choices are for the field. It defaults to `None`, so you would be unable to set any meaningful value. Take a look at the [documentation for Selection fields](http://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/reference/orm.html#openerp.fields.Selection). "The attribute selection is mandatory except in the case of related fields or field extensions."

Answer (score 1):

On the time, when the method `create` is called, your instance isn't created. So `self` doesn't have any instance. `self.status = 'ok'` will change the value of status of nothing.

You can set the value in `values` like that:

```py
@api.model
def create(self, values):
    values['status'] = 'ok'
    line = super(MyClass, self).create(values)
    return line
```

Or change the value after create instance:

```py
@api.model
def create(self, values):
    line = super(MyClass, self).create(values)
    line.status = 'ok'
    return line
```

---

But the method `create` is called, only when a new instance is created. There is the case, that someone want to save the instance. Then you must override the method `write`:

```py
@api.multi
def write(self, vals):
    vals['status'] = 'ok'
    ret = super(FrameworkAgreement, self).write(vals)
```

Comment: exactly as u wrote.I tried to change the value after create

Comment: yes I tried line.status='ok'  and I tried with values['status'] = 'ok' no change no error

Comment: Ok. Tell me please. What do you mind with "click save". What did you do before?

Comment: click save is creating the record for the first time so it's the create function

Comment: status = fields.Selection(
        readonly=False,
        default='tobe',
        related= 'name.status'      
    )                          name is a One2many field

Comment: Now i see it `related= 'name.status'`. Why do you want to change the value of `status`, if it's related field?. Remove tha related option, than it should work